# Formas de criar combobox usando AJAX para preenchimento

Tags: php, html, ajax

Atualmente possuo um combobox em HTML normal:

```
<select name="nomeCombox1" id="nomeCombox1" class="select"> 
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Selecione box1</option>
    <?php
    $res = odbc_exec($conexao, "Select DISTINCT desc from tab1");
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)) {
        echo "<option name='nomeCombox1' value='" . $row['desc'] . "'>" . $row['desc'] . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Esse combo está buscando corretamente os dados.

No passo seguinte, possuo um JS onde busco o que foi selecionado e jogo em uma nova combobox:

```
$("#nomeCombox1").change(function () {
    var idCombox1 = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "js/ajaxBuscar.php",
        data: {idCombox1: idCombox1},
        success: function(data) {
            var q = '<select name="idCombox2" id="idCombox2" class="select"> <option value="0">Escolha</option>';
            for(i=0; i < data.length; i++ ){
                q += '<option value=' + data[i].idCombox2 + '>' + data[i].descricao + '</option>';
            }
            q += '</select>';
            $('#div1').html(q);
        }, error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Esses códigos estão funcionando tudo 100%. Minha dúvida principal seria: Como posso criar esse Combobox2 sem ser via JS? Ou seja, sem ter que jogar `$('#div1').html(q)`. Existe outra forma?

Estou querendo outra maneira porque possuo uma function em JS onde teria que verificar esse valor dessa segunda combobox e preencher um input com o resultado de um outro AJAX. Quando eu coloco a combobox2 direto no HTML funciona. O que estou achando é que, no momento que a página carrega ainda não existe essa segunda combo e dessa maneira o JS não consegue executar corretamente.

Comment: Oi, Felipe, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. O título da pergunta não bate muito com *"Como posso criar um Combobox sem ser via JS?"*... Como assim, sem JS? Se já está usando jQuery/AJAX...

Comment: Esses códigos estão funcionando tudo 100%. Minha dúvida principal seria: Como posso criar esse Combobox2 sem ser via JS? Ou seja, sem ter que jogar $('#div1').html(q). Existe outra forma?

Estou querendo outra maneira porque possuo uma function em JS onde teria que verificar esse valor dessa segunda combobox e preencher um input com o resultado de um outro AJAX. Quando eu coloco a combobox2 direto no HTML funciona. O que estou achando é que, no momento que a página carrega ainda não existe essa segunda combo e dessa maneira o JS não consegue executar corretamente.

Comment: Mas isso que expliquei, já esta na pergunta!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei bem se esse é o seu caso, mas tive alguns problemas parecidos no passado.

Quando o DOM é formado se o seu elemento não tiver sido carregado os eventos do Jquery não serão reconhecidos.

Para exemplificar vamos ver o seguinte trecho de código:

```
$('.classe').click(do());
```

Caso fosse adicionado algum elemento dinamicamente com a class="classe" o bind não iria funcionar porque quando o elemento foi adicionado o bind para ele não foi realizado, só foi realizado para os elementos já carregados.

A solução que encontrei para resolver esse problema foi a seguinte:

```
$(document).on('evento', 'seletor', action());
```

Assim cada vez que um evento é disparado é verificado os elementos que satisfazem o seletor independentemente se já tinha sido carregado inicialmente no DOM ou não.

Para mais informações: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Perfeito Richard. Resolveu o meu problema! Não conhecia esse tipo de "disparo"!

Meu código ficou assim: $(document).on('change', 'select[name=idCombox2]', function(){

Comment: Que bom que foi útil! Sei que sofri um pouco com isto antes de descobrir isto.